# sum values of a delimited text file through linux/unix

Tags: text-processing

I have a delimited text file like this

```
Code|Grade_CD|FCST|Change_Prob|target
11245|yyy|2020-01-01|25.0124|2020
11245|yyy|2020-01-01|25.0124|2020
11245|yyy|2020-01-01|22.0124|2020
11245|yyy|2020-01-01|22.0124|2020
```

I need to add all the values under the column "Change_Prob" by ignoring the header in the file and print the sum as  Total change_Prob = 94.0496

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F\| 'NR>1 { sum=sum+$4; }; END { print sum; }' input
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'|' 'NR > 1 { sum = sum + $4 }; END { print "Total change_Prob = " sum }' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  col='Change_Prob' 
  printf 'Total %s = ' "$col"
  c=$(head -n 1 | tr '|' '\n' | grep -nxF -- "$col" | cut -d: -f1)
  cut -d"|" -f"$c" - | paste -sd+ | bc -l
} < file
Total Change_Prob = 94.0496
```

Or if we already know the 4th column has the data then we could also do this:

```
$ printf 'Total Change_Prob = '
$ tail -n+2 inp | cut -d"|" -f4 - |  tr :- :_ |
   dc -e '[pq]sq[?z1=q+l?x]s?czdd=?'
Total Change_Prob = 94.0496
```